# What personality traits correlate with estrogen?

Tags: neuroscience, personality

I'm looking for psychological traits that are proved to correlate with estrogen levels. Anything of specific behavior, attitudes, life styles, emotions, preferences, you name it.

(I'm looking for links to scientific reports)

Comment: I think none. Personality traits are related to personality and not sexuality.

Comment: @Andrewski, there are many studies saying it's wrong as higher estrogen can make behaviour more dominant. Can't recall for a paper now, though.